# On action, change user role

Tags: user-roles

wonder if you can help me.

I'm trying to get an action (geodir_after_save_listing) to change a user role.

Basically, in Geo Directory, when the user submits a business listing, I want to change their role from "member" to "member_with_business"

I believe the geo_dir_after_save_listing is still a relevant action (awaiting response from GeoDirectory support) so IMO the php snippet below should work?

```
add_action('geodir_after_save_listing', 'change_user_role_when_submit_business');

function change_user_role_when_submit_business( $last_post_id, $request_info ) {
  $gd_post_type = geodir_get_current_posttype();

    if ($gd_post_type == 'gd_place') {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = $user->roles;
    
    if (in_array('member', $roles)){
      
        $user->add_role( 'member_with_business' );
        $user->remove_role( 'member' );
    }
  }
}
```

Any thoughts from those more php savvy than me?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things perhaps spring to mind - when using `add_action` you'll need to [provide how many of the arguments you're planning on using](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/). Default 1. You're not using request info so get rid of that. Second bit `geodir_get_current_posttype()` [link](https://github.com/GeoDirectory/geodirectory/blob/2261e50e70a44ea1e39224a2de218317d0b0fbf1/geodirectory-functions/taxonomy_functions.php#L404)

Read through how the function works and make sure it makes sense and would work in the context you are using it. It looks like it reads a query var from the URL - is that there?

Another option could just be to look this up yourself - looks like you've got the `$last_post_id` variable. Can you not find out the info you need from that?

Plenty of var_dumps and die can help you diagnose what you're missing. [Looks like the plugin author leaves most of them in the code anyway!](https://github.com/GeoDirectory/geodirectory/blob/2261e50e70a44ea1e39224a2de218317d0b0fbf1/geodirectory-functions/taxonomy_functions.php#L1472)

Comment: Thanks @Bysander, apologies I didn't see your response till now.

I had some support from the plugin developer and this code seemed to work.

`add_action( 'geodir_post_saved', 'gd_snippet_210409_on_post_saved', 9999, 4 );

function gd_snippet_210409_on_post_saved( $postarr, $gd_post, $post, $update ) {
 
 if ( $gd_post['post_type'] == 'gd_place' ) {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();

  if ( ! empty( $user->roles ) && in_array( 'member', $user->roles ) ) {
   $user->set_role( 'member_with_business' );
  }
 }
}`

However on page load, it instantly saves and changes member role